# how to setup cronjob in magento 1.9.3

Tags: php, custom, script, cronjobs, magento-1.9.3.2

I am trying to set a cronjob for export order to another website in Magento 1.9.3

please, anyone, have an idea then plz share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your modules **config.xml** put the following:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <dolphininvoicecron>
                <class>Dolphin_Invoice_Model</class>
            </dolphininvoicecron>                         
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <rdolphininvoicecron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>dolphininvoicecron/cron::setStatus</model>
                </run>
            </dolphininvoicecron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

In app/code/local/Dolphin/Invoice/Model/**Cron.php** add the following:

```
<?php
class Dolphin_Invoice_Model_Cron {
    public function setStatus() {
        Mage::log("WORKS!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing...